# JSF ValueChangeListener not working

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, event-handling

I am learning how to use events with JSF. For some reason, the program is not changing the value in the text field when I change the value of the dropdown menu. The page loads and shows "Germany", but does not change the text field to "DE". Any suggestions?

Index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{Bean.selectedItem}" valueChangeListener="#{Bean.changeEvent}" onchange="submit()"  >
                <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.itemsList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <br />
            <h:inputText value="#{Bean.selectedItem}" />
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

MyBean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
@ManagedBean (name = "Bean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

private static ArrayList menuItems;
private String selectedItem = "EN";
static {
    menuItems = new ArrayList();
    menuItems.add(new SelectItem("EN", "English"));
    menuItems.add(new SelectItem("DE", "Germany"));
}

public ArrayList getItemsList() {
    return this.menuItems;
}

public void setSelectedItem(String item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
}

public String getSelectedItem() {
    return selectedItem;
}

public void changeEvent(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    selectedItem = e.getNewValue().toString();
}

}
```

Comment: Does that input field *really* need to be an input field? Shouldn't it rather be readonly or an output field?

Comment: I am just doing this to learn how it works. I have another larger program where I am using it to automatically input a default value upon selection. This is for testing. I just need to figure out how to update the text field when the dropdown menu value is changed.

Answer (score 17):

You're basically abusing the `valueChangeListener` as an `actionListener`. The value change listener is intented to have access to **both** the old and new value, right in between when the new input value is been submitted and the model value is been updated, so that you can for example add a log entry about the value change. You are apparently not interested in the old value. You're not interested in the value change event at all. You're only interested in the new model value. So you shouldn't be using the value change listener at all.

Normally, you'd like to do this job in an action listener method. You can use `<f:ajax>` to define an ajax action listener:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{Bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.itemsList}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{Bean.changeEvent}" render="input" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{Bean.selectedItem}" />
```

with

```
public void changeEvent() {
    selectedItem = selectedItem;
}
```

But since you've bound the input to the same property as the dropdown, the whole listener is superfluous. Just the following should do it for you:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{Bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.itemsList}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="input" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{Bean.selectedItem}" />
```

The problem which you're seeing is because the `onchange="submit()"` essentially submits the **whole** form, including all other input fields. As JSF processes input fields in sequence and you've bound the both fields to the same property, the value of `<h:inputText>` will override the value of `<h:selectOneMenu>`. As per my comment on the question, you would not have this problem when you made it a `<h:inputText readonly="true">` or a `<h:outputText>` (so that it won't submit its value to the server).

Answer (score 1):

Change this to output text component and see if it works

```
<h:inputText value="#{Bean.selectedItem}" />
```

to

```
<h:outputText value="#{Bean.selectedItem}" />
```

Regards!

Comment: That worked. How come it does not work on the input text field? The program is for a user to select their database engine (MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, PostgreSQL). I need to put a default port in the text field, and allow the user to edit the field if they are using another port.

Comment: In this case you can try to bind another listener to the inputText component (like onchange). I can highly recommend using the f:ajax tag as well as the other poster above has mentioned. Hope this works!